# Help me hack this speaker, where would I introduce DC voltage

Tags: power-supply, dc, speakers, converter, hacking

I have a speaker that runs off of AC (there is a switching converter within the speaker) I'm attempting to convert it to battery power, From my understanding the speaker runs off of 5V (someone else did a similar conversion). so here goes

1. Where would I solder a wire to run directly from DC. I'm assuming it would be after the switching mode power supply. Also I know that there is some conditioning going on there, so I'm not sure the implications of bypassing it.

Attached are photos of the unit 
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please make another photo of what is in the upper right corner of the first picture. There should be a beefy rectifier.

Comment: @venny i added the photos, can't locate the rectifier, although there is a ton of glue everywhere

Comment: I think D302 might be it. No, scratch that. D303 and D301 on the backside.

Comment: @ Ignacio can you elaborate a little? what the polarity? should i hook it up and measure the voltage across those two components, and see if it's 5V or so?

Comment: D301 and D303 are on the transformer's primary side, i would not say that is the output rectifier. You should use a continuity tester to find out what is between the transformer and the big capacitors' positive terminal.

Comment: Careful with continuity testing and false positives around large caps though. **And make sure the caps are fully discharged first.**

Comment: Thinking about it further, it should be safe to put the battery across the filter capacitor, with no modifications.

Comment: @venny pardon my ignorance but which one is the filtering capacitor the duel 2200uf? or the 100uf that is closer to the coil (to the left)

Comment: @user379468 Yes, the big brown cylinders. The white strip denotes negative terminal. Please be careful and start with a weak power supply.

Comment: bingo, it worked .... turns out its 24v not 5v, but I hooked it up to a 24v drill battery and it works !

Comment: You should put that as an answer and mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because very specific question, won't be useful to others in the future. Solved already.

Answer (score 1):

I measured the voltage across the two capacitors (as venny suggested) and found that the voltage was 20V. Then I connected a 20v rechargeable battery across that capacitor and was able to operate the speaker from battery power.