# Help me hack this other speaker: Where would I introduce two different DC voltages?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, speakers, hacking

I already asked a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130065/help-me-hack-this-speaker-where-would-i-introduce-dc-voltage) about a similar speaker. I am also trying to convert a larger speaker in the same fashion.

I open the speaker, and can identify the power supply and rectifier (I believe) just as in the last question. I measure the voltage across the medium-sized capacitors (1) and it measures 24V... now I try to hook up the capacitors in the same fashion I did the first time to 24V DC, only this time it does not work.

I believe that in this system there are two different power systems. Because when I measure the voltage across a second set of capacitors (2) it's 5V, I can't really tell if I'm jumping the shark, I'm wondering if I introduced a second DC 5V source, if I can get this speaker also to operate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe there are other supply sections, but the capacitors marked 2 are probably not related to it. My gues would be the two black capacitors on the right side of the transformer (maybe they form a symmetric supply for analog circuitry).

Comment: @venny, would powering up one side of the supply not effect the other? When I put a DC voltage across the capacitors to the bottom of the transformer, I get the same voltage across the ones to the side, I know this is shot in the dark but is there anything else I can do do determine whats going on? thanks for your help.... Also, the header pins to the right go to another board ... thats the one that I can't get to power one when I hook it up to DC

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know enough about linear and switching power supplies to recognize what you're working with, then you probably got lucky the first time.  Or you followed someone else's instructions for that exact design who did know what they were doing or got lucky themselves.

In general, some things to watch out for:

1. Many topologies can handle being backdriven when powered off themselves, but not all of them.  If you find the right place to hook up your battery, the AC supply will most likely do nothing, but in some cases it may actually present a short-circuit to your battery.  This could be because it uses an inductor to eliminate most of the switching noise from the output, and at least one of the switching transistors themselves defaults to "on" (some types do that, or perhaps the battery voltage gets around enough to turn it on).  Inductors pass DC like a short-circuit, and the stuck-on transistor completes the short across the battery.  Or if it's a linear supply, the regulator will probably NOT like having its output powered directly.
2. Multiple power rails are by no means guaranteed to be connected.  They could be, if the primary supply produces a relatively high voltage which then feeds one or more regulators, but more likely is that there is a single oscillator (which could be the AC input directly or a higher-frequency clock) that drives a single transformer that produces all of the output voltages in raw form.  Each output then has its own post-processing, so to speak, but you can't feed DC back through the transformer.  If your unit does any sort of active signal processing besides amplification, then it probably does have multiple internal supplies.  (volume, balance, and simple bass/treble can be passive, but that's about it, and even those functions could be active anyway)
3. Some of the capacitors may not be used for the power supply, but to AC-couple the signal from one module to another.  One example of this might be to offset it from being centered on 0V to being centered between the internal supply rails.  The voltage across that cap would then be equal to 1/2 the supply voltage.  Connecting a battery to that one will not power the circuit and might make it clip (distort) easily because you're forcing the signal to sit too close to one rail or the other.  Or if the cap is used for something else, then the symptoms might be different.

The way I would approach this is to reverse-engineer the circuit under a bright light so I could see the copper tracks, starting at the AC input.  Do some research on switching power supply topologies and see if you can match one up with what you have.  By that time, you might have learned enough to determine if you do indeed have multiple supplies and if you need to unsolder something to isolate it or just leave it in there as a diode-OR.

Comment: here is a link to high res images of the board, as well as two mov file (a quick render that fades top to bottom). Can identify, the input capacitor, bridge rectifier, transformer, and output coil an capacitor, but beyond that I'm lost. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Byj7dwK3qRtwbFJ1SEZNX2MydTg&usp=sharing

Comment: A lot of my projects are just as much for education as they are for results, if not more.  Quite often, I find myself learning things that I thought were completely unrelated at first but turned out to be critical.  I think this might be one of them.  Time for you to learn about circuit design and layout.  :)

Comment: Indeed, think I might punt on this though, maybe in time i can figure it out

Comment: I ended up just using an inverter for the larger unit, although it's not very efficient, the time it would take me to reverse engineer this thing was unknown